# Swift Vision's rectangle detection fails after Core Image's perspective correction

Tags: swift, image-processing, detection, core-image, vision

I'm using macOS Big Sur Version 11.2.3 and Xcode Version 12.4.
I want to get the outer square of a sudoku image which has a perspectivic distortion.
I do it in the following way:

1. Perform a rectangle detect request. This delivers the points of the outer rectangle.
2. Perform a perspective correction. This delivers a perfect quadratic rectangle.
3. Now I want to crop the image at the sudokus outer frame.
4. Perform a second rectangle detect request for the perspective corrected image to get the rectangle for the cropping operation.

Surprisingly the rectangle detection delivers as result an empty Array.

I have a suspection, what the reason could be.

Printing out the properties of the original CGImage delivers:

```
Original image:
    <CGImage 0x7f92e4415560> (IP)
        <<CGColorSpace 0x6000035faf40> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)>
            width = 2448, height = 3264, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 9792
            kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | 0 (default byte order)  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked
            is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes
    2021-04-06 19:15:04.445374+0200 StackExchangeHilfe[1959:100561] Metal API Validation Enabled
```

Printing out the properties of the perspective corrected CGImage delivers:

```
    Corrected image:
    <CGImage 0x7f92f451f180> (DP)
        <<CGColorSpace 0x6000035fae80> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)>
            width = 2073, height = 2194, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 8320
            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | 0 (default byte order)  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked
            is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes
```

There is a difference in the bitmapInfo:

Original Image: **kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast**

Corrected Image: **kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast**

Any other CIFilter does not change the bitmapInfo.

I tried to change this value, but it is a read-only variable.
However, maybe my suspection is completely wrong.

In any case can somebody help?
Thanks in advance.

```
    import UIKit
    import Vision

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var origImageView: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var correctedImageView: UIImageView!
        
        let imageName = "sudoku"
        var origImage: UIImage!
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            origImage = UIImage(named: imageName)
            origImageView.image = origImage
            let correctedImage = performOperationsWithUIImage(origImage)
            correctedImageView.image = correctedImage
        }
        
        func performOperationsWithUIImage(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
            let cgImage = image.cgImage!
            print("Original image:")
            print("\(String(describing: cgImage))")
            
            // Create rectangle detect request
            let rectDetectRequest = VNDetectRectanglesRequest()
             // Customize & configure the request to detect only certain rectangles.
            rectDetectRequest.maximumObservations = 8 // Vision currently supports up to 16.
            rectDetectRequest.minimumAspectRatio = 0.8 // height / width
            rectDetectRequest.quadratureTolerance = 30
            rectDetectRequest.minimumSize = 0.5
            rectDetectRequest.minimumConfidence = 0.6
            
            // Create a request handler.
            let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, orientation: .up, options: [:])
            // Send the requests to the request handler.
            do {
                try imageRequestHandler.perform([rectDetectRequest])
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Failed to perform first image request: \(error)")
                }
            guard let results = rectDetectRequest.results as? [VNRectangleObservation]
            else {return nil}
            print("\nFirst rectangle request result:")
            print("\(results.count) rectangle(s) detected:")
            print("\(String(describing: results))")
            
            // Perform pespective correction
            let width = Int(cgImage.width)
            let height = Int(cgImage.height)
            guard let filter = CIFilter(name:"CIPerspectiveCorrection")  else { return nil }
            
            filter.setValue(CIImage(image: image), forKey: "inputImage")
            filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: VNImagePointForNormalizedPoint(results.first!.topLeft, width, height)), forKey: "inputTopLeft")
            filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: VNImagePointForNormalizedPoint(results.first!.topRight, width, height)), forKey: "inputTopRight")
            filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: VNImagePointForNormalizedPoint(results.first!.bottomLeft, width, height)), forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
            filter.setValue(CIVector(cgPoint: VNImagePointForNormalizedPoint(results.first!.bottomRight, width, height)), forKey: "inputBottomRight")
            
            guard
                let outputCIImage = filter.outputImage,
                let outputCGImage = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(outputCIImage, from: outputCIImage.extent)  else {return nil}
            
            print("\nCorrected image:")
            print("\(String(describing: outputCGImage))")
            
            // Perform another rectangle detection
            let newImageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: outputCGImage, orientation: .up, options: [:])
            // Send the requests to the request handler.
            do {
                try newImageRequestHandler.perform([rectDetectRequest])
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Failed to perform second image request: \(error)")
                }
            guard let newResults = rectDetectRequest.results as? [VNRectangleObservation]
            else {return nil}
            print("\nSecond rectangle request result:")
            print("\(newResults.count) rectangle(s) detected:")
            print("\(String(describing: newResults))")

            return UIImage(cgImage: outputCGImage)
        }


    }
```

[image]

Comment: I would guess that vision can't find the rectangle the second time because it's too large and almost fills the entire image. Maybe you can try to not crop as much when you do the perspective correction.